# SignumFramework in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is possible to use the [Signum Framework](http://www.signumframework.com/Default.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) with previous versions of .NET, 2.0 specifically?

Comment: I think you posted to the wrong place. The original post was deleted (and I bet this one is as well).

Comment: Disagree with the "offensive" vote on this; there is nothing offensive about the question, unless it is a sock-puppet for the signum team.

Comment: It's a fair question. Olmo explains the situation in his answer below.

Comment: Thanks EndangeredMassa! 3 months working on an open source project and the begining couldn't have been worst :)

Comment: I don't think even a sock puppet would necessarily be a problem; SO is fine with posting a question with the intention of answering it yourself. It shouldn't matter who posted the question or why as long as it abides by community standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the members of the signum team, and the reason why we've thought of SO as the place to get all the questions about our free ORM is that we think it adjusts nicely to the principle of answering technical questions by programmers, for programmers.

We accept (and undertsand) no publicity can be posted here, and won't do it, that's why we removed our welcome post. However, we don't see the reason why the questions can't be posted here, as this is a place meant for that (as well as we published the code in codeplex, a place designed to publish open source code). Anyway internal discussions or bugs won't go here, those will stay in Codeplex, this will be just a place to ask the technical questions.

The reasons why we think SO is the best forum alternative around are:

- The community and the rules that govern SO make it the most effective place to ask technical Q&A (in spite of it gave us some headache today).
- A lot of the questions related to Signum Framework are closely related to other areas, such as LINQ, WPF, WCF... So it looks more natural a generic forum like this.(i.e. How to create a dynamic IQueryable)
- It's the most technically advanced forum available.

If this doesn't really acomplish the SO primciples, we'll stop referring SO as the place to ask us questions.

About the puppet thing, cad is an old friend of us. He had this question and he used the normal way to ask it. I'm sad he got 2 reputation points less now.

Back to the question:

Marc is right, it works with .Net 3.5 only. Signum.Utilities, the basic assembly, uses Linq features intensively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with nor associated with signum, but as a LINQ provider, it is **extremely** likely that this uses the `Expression` API for the LINQ side of things (i.e. not just delegates). As such, I doubt very much that it will work with anything before .NET 3.5.

update: there is also now a signum support channel [here](http://www.signumframework.com/MainPage.ashx).